# Clear the model and the solver,

Tags: solver, ojalgo

I am using the OjAlgo for a linear programming problem which runs on a small gateway (not that much of computation capability). The inputs are changing and I solve the problem each 5 minutes. Before clearing the model and recreating the new one, it goes to UNEXPLORED status after almost 10 solving. Then I figured out it is possible to dispose the model and then recreate new model each time. This helps and it got better. But still after a while it gets into UNEXPLORED state and never gets out. The thing is restoring the java application will solve the issue but again after a while it gets into the same UNEXPLORED mode.
Then I created an instance of Intermediate by getModel().prepare() and then dispose it. I see dispose method in the Intermediate has some clearing for the solver also. It helps a lot and now I almost don't see an UNEXPLORED but a few time I still get UNEXPLORED. And when it gets to UNEXPLORED it gets stuck. Seems it has something to do with the cleaning up. Is there another thing that I still need to do to clean the model and the solver? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it's not your code/problem formulation that's the cause? Can you recreate invoking the same problem multiple times, or is changing the problem part of the cause? A problem that gave you UNEXPLORED, can that be solved later in a new JVM?

Comment: If it is the code problem it should not be solved at all. If I stop the JAVA program it will be fine again. The thing is it goes to UNEXPLORED status and not get out. When it is trapped stopping the JAVA program and starting it again will resolve the issue. Could you please shed some light on how to restart the solver? I mean clear everything solver and the model.